# Automatically selects list ID for Toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select list id automatically using Jquery. When I click on some list it should take its id and allow toggle. Now I want that JQuery automatically gets the ID`` of clicked Item and perform the toggle.

By toggle I mean when I click on Catalog other list items will hide. And only Catalog list will show.

I want to implement below Jquery :

```
**$("").click(function(){
    $("").toggle();
});*
```

*

```
<div id="aside">
    <div id="column">
        <ul>
            <li id="dashboard"><a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard</a></li>
            <li id = "catalogs"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Catalog</a>

                <div id="q">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Catogeries</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Departure Location</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Return Location </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Cities </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Vendor </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Discount Coupons</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="">Remaining Seats </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="user"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Users</a>
                <div id="g">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Customer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Agents</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="catalog"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Customers</a>
                <div id="s">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Customer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Orders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Reward System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="repot"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reports</a>
                <div id="k">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Monthly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Comission Report</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: toggle what? explain. And also add the jquery code.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` will give the id of clicked element when binded to click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#column li").click(function() {
    $('#column li li').hide();
    $(this).find('li').show();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qazzfxp/1/

or:

```
$("#column li").click(function() {
    $('#column li li').not($(this).find('li')).hide();
    $(this).find('li').toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qazzfxp/2/

Answer (score 0):

It may fixe your problem

```
$("#column li").click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qazzfxp/)